# Exceute script on publishing or updating a new custom post record

Tags: customization, scripts

I should run a script which is executed when publishing a new or when updating an existing CPT record. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using WordPress hooks and the `save_post` action. You'll need to add your custom script to your theme's `functions.php` file or create a custom plugin. Here's how to do it:

**For All Custom Post Types:**

1. Open your theme's `functions.php` file or create a custom plugin.
2. Add the following code to register the `save_post` action hook:

```php
add_action('save_post', 'your_custom_function', 10, 3);

function your_custom_function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // Check if this is a new post or an update
    if ($update || 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        // Your script or code to be executed here
        // You can use $post_id and $post to access the post's data
        // Example: your_custom_script($post_id);
    }
}
```

3. Replace `'your_custom_function'` with the name of your custom function that contains the script you want to execute.
4. Inside the `your_custom_function` function, you can check whether the post is being updated or published as a new post. If it's an update or a new post being published, your custom script or code will be executed.
5. Be sure to replace the comment `// Your script or code to be executed here` with the actual code or script you want to run when any custom post type (CPT) record is published or updated.
6. Save your `functions.php` file or activate your custom plugin.

Now, whenever a new custom post type record is published or updated, your custom script or code will be executed automatically for all custom post types.

**For a Specific Custom Post Type:**

If you want to execute the script only for a specific custom post type, you can add a conditional check within the `your_custom_function` function like this:

```php
add_action('save_post', 'your_custom_function', 10, 3);

function your_custom_function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // Check if this is a new post or an update
    if ($update || 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        // Check if the post type is 'your_custom_post_type'
        if ($post->post_type === 'your_custom_post_type') {
            // Your script or code to be executed here
            // You can use $post_id and $post to access the post's data
            // Example: your_custom_script($post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `'your_custom_post_type'` with the actual name of your custom post type. With this code, the script will only execute when a new or updated post of the specified custom post type is published.

To apply the custom script to multiple custom post types using an array, you can modify the `your_custom_function` function as follows:

```php
add_action('save_post', 'your_custom_function', 10, 3);

function your_custom_function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // Check if this is a new post or an update
    if ($update || 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        // Define an array of custom post types to target
        $custom_post_types = array('custom_post_type1', 'custom_post_type2', 'custom_post_type3');
        
        // Check if the post type is in the array
        if (in_array($post->post_type, $custom_post_types)) {
            // Your script or code to be executed here
            // You can use $post_id and $post to access the post's data
            // Example: your_custom_script($post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code:

1. Replace `custom_post_type1`, `custom_post_type2`, `custom_post_type3`, etc., with the names of the custom post types you want to target.
2. The `in_array` function is used to check if the post's type (`$post->post_type`) is in the specified array of custom post types.
3. If the post type matches any of the custom post types in the array, your custom script or code will be executed when a new post or an update occurs for any of those specified post types.

By using this approach, you can easily apply the custom script to multiple custom post types by adding or removing them from the array as needed.